# RenderControl does not evaluate Response.Writes but evaluates <%= %>?

Tags: asp.net

Why does calling page.RenderControl not evaulate `<% Response.Write("foo") %>` but it does evaluate `<%= "bar" %>`? Is there something else I should be calling instead?

I was under the impression that  [`<%= %>` was shorthand for `Response.Write`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151448/response-write-vs) as it is in classic ASP.

```
... <p><%= "foo" %><% Response.Write("bar"); %></p> ...
```

Render Control code...

```
string output;

using (var mem = new StringWriter())
using (var writer = new XhtmlTextWriter(mem))
{
     page.RenderControl(writer);
     output = mem.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
}
```

Outputs...

```
Expected: "<p>foobar</p>" 
Actual: "<p>foo</p>"
```

Answer (score 3):

<%= %> is the same as Response.Write in asp.net. Thats why <%= "bar" %> works.

You are missing a semicolon at the end of <% Response.Write("bar") %> . Thats why it is not working.

Comment: There is a semicolon there and it is not rendering bar. That is not the reason why it's not working.

Comment: were you able to make it work ? I got busy with some other stuff, if it worked for you then fine, else i can fire up visual studio and see if we can generate some clue ?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with yours, my solution is just use `<%=...%>` instead of `response.write();`
Personally think the reason looks like former render earlier than `response.write()`. Once program reach `response.write()` function the `RenderControl` object has no control over it even if in server-side tag.