# Classic ASP query string variable is both set and unset

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic

I have this code:

```
<%If CInt(Request.QueryString("OpenYouthHistory")) > 0 Then %>
<script>
    var yid = <% Request.QueryString("OpenYouthHistory") %>;
    window.open("YouthHistory.asp?YouthID=" + yid);
</script>
<% End If %>
```

I want to open the YouthHistory.asp page in a popup window if the `OpenYouthHistory` query string variable is set. However when I run it with a value of, say, 210, then I get this output:

```
<script>
    var yid = ;
    window.open("YouthHistory.asp?YouthID=" + yid);
</script>
```

Which of course is invalid JavaScript. But why is the `yid` variable not getting a value? If the query string variable really is blank, why is the `<script>` tag even rendering? I'm so confused...

Comment: Would recommend - [Response.Write vs <%= %>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/151448)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<%=` which is a shortcut for `<% Response.Write`

```
<%If CInt(Request.QueryString("OpenYouthHistory")) > 0 Then %>
<script>
    var yid = <%=Request.QueryString("OpenYouthHistory") %>;
    window.open("YouthHistory.asp?YouthID=" + yid);
</script>
<% End If %>
```

Comment: Aha, thanks! Totally forgot about `<%=`!

Comment: One thing I will say when working with injected ASP variables surround them with quotes so if they are empty it doesn't cause a syntax error in JavaScript. Something like `var yid = "<%=Request.QueryString("OpenYouthHistory") %>";`, that way you can use JavaScript to check the length of `yid` to see if it contains a valid value rather than `var yid = ;` causing a syntax error.

Comment: your comment makes sense however there is `<%If CInt(` in front of it, so only numeric value will go to the injected code.

Comment: @alex it does, I did notice that but as OP focused in on the `<%=` I wanted to make the point clear about making sure values are valid before attempting to inject them. The answer is absolutely right, it wasn't a criticism.

Comment: while I fully understand your comment, we should not confuse OP telling about syntax errors as values will not be necessary invalid without quotes - javascript specification doesn't require quotes for numeric literals and `var yid = 1;` will be absolutely valid from any point of view.